# how can I make a gif in ReadMe.md more smaller

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to make a gif smaller in the readme section.
is there a way like "https://user-images.......gif  => 250x350"
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use an `img` tag and size your gif accordingly

e.g  `<img src=<MY_GIF>  height="275">`